# How to access Volley response in another Class or Scope?

Tags: java, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

Hi there I am struggling to understand how exactly Volley request works. I have done similar things in NodeJs and the process seemed more intuitive.

```
String url = "http://my-json-feed";

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        //All I want is to use the response outside this scope 
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // TODO: Handle error

    }
});

MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);



//Example: How can I access the response here or in any other class?
```

In NodeJS this same process looks similar to this (with the help of node-fetch)

```
const response = await fetch(url);
const json = await response.json();
console.log(json);
```

And I can basically access json from anywhere in the same file or I can return it from the current function and use it anywhere where I call that function. I want to ask how can I do something similar in Java?

Comment: You need to make a method to execute when `onResponse` is called, or, alternatively, create a field for the response use `Object#wait` and `Object#notify` to pause the thread until the field is set.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If I create a method and call it from inside onResponse, then won’t the response of that method be trapped inside the onResponse? Or am I missing sth?

Comment: Create a method with parameters and pass `response` to it. For example, `public static void doSomething(JSONObject response)`